# File size mismatch by a huge margin in properties?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, filesystems

I have this single file on my HDD and it shows that its size is 150bytes but in properties tab it shows as 850 GB, What's happening here ?

[image: file_screenshot]

Comment: `\\` is a illegal character for filenames so the Properties window is probably showing the size of D:\

Comment: oh yeah feels like it, I just renamed it and it just changed my folder name.

Comment: and now `rm -fr` on linux returns this `rm: cannot remove 'ocr_laptop_data/crisp/hello1': Directory not empty`